# Configuring TapJoy Creating Dex FIle issue

Tags: android, dex, tapjoy

I have multiple libraries in my libs folder in android. When I try to add "Tapjoy", I get the error:

> unable to execute dex method id not in 0 0xffff 65536 android problem
>   is  coming

and, when I am trying to configure build path and adding external jars,

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.tapjoy.TapjoyConnect
```

I'm stuck on this problem. Can any one give me solution?

Answer (score 0):

Congratulation you have reached the 65K method limit you have two options :

a) Clean up some code by removing unnecessary libraries / using ProGuard.

b) Multidex solution , follow these steps

1. Make sure your Android SDK Build and Android Support Repository are updated to latest version.
2. Modify your `build.gradle` by adding the support dex lib and enabling the multidex

   ```
   android {
   compileSdkVersion 21
   buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

   defaultConfig {
       ...
       minSdkVersion 14
       targetSdkVersion 21
       ...

       // Enabling multidex support.
       multiDexEnabled true
   }
   ...
   }

   dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0' 
   }
   ```
3. Modify your manifest:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
        <application
         ...
         android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
         ...
        </application>
   </manifest>
   ```

p.s if you already extend Application then just override the attachBaseContext method

```
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

for more info:
[Building Apps with Over 65K Methods](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)